# Adding bootstrap popover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I am setting the HTML content of my table, and I want to show popover on hover over each cell of table.I am using bootstrap for this.

in javascript:

```
html = html + "<td>"+data[i]["initial_score"]+"</td>";
        html = html + "<td onmouseover=\"showpopover('"+main_image_data['score_reason']+"')\">"+main_image_data['bonus']+"</td>";
        html = html + "<td>"+variant_data['bonus']+"</td>";
```

showpopover function:

```
showpopover=function(message){
    $(this).popover({ placement: "bottom",title:"Score",content:"<div>THIS IS SCORE</div>"});   
};
```

But , when I hover over the cell, it doesnt show any popover.
Am I using 'this' wrongly in showpopover function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/zcJuf/6/) Hope it helps you!

```
 $popover = $(val).popover({ 
    trigger: "hover",
    placement: "bottom",
    title:"Score",
    content:"<div>THIS IS SCORE</div>"
 });
```

Comment: As content is html be sure to add {html: true} to your options for the popover.